# problem with objects_of_daily_use_finder!

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I have to use objects_of_daily_use_finder package for recognizing different objects, but i have a problem with output of this package because it does not publish anything in  "found_template" (from the output of the visualization i think the object is recognized!)

anybody faced this problem before?

thanks,

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/30775/problem-with-objects_of_daily_use_finder!/) by [Alireza](https://answers.ros.org/users/1637/alireza/) on ROS Answers with karma: 717 on 2012-03-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes, I spent some days making it work. The current state of that code is not perfect :)
The templates are available, you only have to insert some code to publish them.

If you only need detection and you have a fast CPU then this package might fit your needs after a bit of coding.

What this package can give you:

- fast SIFT-based feature matching for
  templates (fast: compared to other
  implementation)
- single detection results ("publishes" matched template)
- detection result names (now it's only printed I think but could get the file name of the template as a result)
- high false detection rate (based on my experiences)
- no pose estimation (important if you are considering grasping)

If you are further interested in this topic we can share experiences in private and create a summary for example on the ros wiki.

---

Originally posted by [Bence Magyar](https://answers.ros.org/users/1102/bence-magyar/) with karma: 358 on 2012-03-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0